# Code for PIR Motion Sensor not showing any output with Blynk

Tags: c++, c, debugging, arduino-esp8266, blynk

So in this project, I'm trying to connect my PIR sensor switch on Blynk to switch on/off through my phone. Although this code compiles just fine, I'm not getting any output from the PIR sensor or LED. I connect it through an ESP8266-01 with my Arduino board. So now I'm confused with either my code has an error or just my PIR sensor is not working. Please help. Thank you guys in advance.

```
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>

int led = 9;
int sensor =2;
int state = LOW;    //default, no motion detected
int val = 0;       //variable to store sensor data status

char auth[] = "aIUaQ3TPypvl9uajcOgMHhaWpSkc8dkz";
char ssid[] = "im kinda sus";
char pass[] = "ilovearduino";

void setup(){
Serial.begin(115200);     //getting ready to communicate
Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
pinMode(led,OUTPUT);        //define led as the output
pinMode(sensor, INPUT);      //define sensor as the input
}


void pirSensor(){
val = digitalRead(sensor);    //read sensor input
if(val == HIGH){    
digitalWrite(led,HIGH);     //if value is high, led light up
delay(500);

if(state == LOW){     //if pir state is low
  Serial.println("Motion Detected!");   //print this line
  state = HIGH;   //pir sensor detect motion
}
}
else if(state == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);   // if not led turn off
      delay(500);
      Serial.println("Motion Stopped!");    // print this line
      state = LOW; 
      }

}

BLYNK_WRITE(V0){
int led = param.asInt(); //led is connected to virtual pin 0
}

void loop(){
Blynk.run();  //blynk starts to run

}
```

Comment: test the sensor with simplest possible sketch (next time before asking)

Comment: yea the sensor is working, but i still couldn't find the problem

Comment: the `pirSensor()` function is not used in the sketch in Question